# Connect to MySQL database via terminal command on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, shell

I have been trying to connect to company MySQL database via terminal on my Mac. I downloaded MySQL CLI via 'home brew' on my Mac:

```
$brew install mysql
```

Then, I followed the format as below:

```
$mysql -u user_name -p passwords -h host_name database_name
```

Yet, I got error message "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host_name' (60)". Could any one tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You are supplying host_name ... replace with actual host machine name

Comment: Yes, I was using the actual host name, user name and passwords. Here, for indication, I just put an placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

We definitely need more details to help you , but with a quick guess I think that you need to start MySQL first

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Also , it is a good idea to check the status of the server before you try to connect to it.

```
   sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status
```

*Paths depend on the installation path of MySQL

Comment: Hi Yeikel! Thanks so much for the help! I was trying to execute sql query via terminal on my Mac OSX to connect to our company MySQL database. I was managed to set up SSH tunnel via 'SSH Tunnel Manager' app and successfully connected to MySQL database on 'Sequal Pro' app. However, when I tried to connect MySQL on terminal with the above steps, it returned my that error message. I have also tried to start mysql server with your command but it says "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/tw-mba-mli.pid).". Is it due the missing of PID file? Please let me know.

Comment: Also, I have checked the .err file and found out the message: [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35.

Comment: @MarkLi The error is telling you  that you have MySQL running in your computer and that's why you can't start a second instance. I find it suspicious that you are able to connect with Sequal Pro and not with the command line. Can you paste the exact command you're executing ?

Comment: Sure! In the terminal, I executed the command "mysql -u mmr -p XATtAoqaU6JahuMib2BH -h db-kredd-ro-app-002.atla.company.com roi_add_prod" to try to connect the database. Yet, now I am receiving the mysql cli user menu as result. Does it indicate that I am passing the wrong parameters to the command? Before executing the command, I made sure that the SSH tunnel was connected and 'Sequal Pro' was off. Also, I have tried to run command - "sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status" and it said "MySQL is not running".

Comment: @MarkLi Did you try to stop the server first and then try to start it? Do a full reboot of the machine before trying to do so. Also , what about passing 'localhost' as the host?

Comment: I tried the command "sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop" but it returns "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!". I have also tried the "mysql" in "System preference" which I downloaded before on Mac to start or stop server. It just freezzed after I click the 'mysql' icon.. When I try command "mysql --host=localhost" to connect localhost, it returns "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)". What would be the problem? Again, thanks Yeikel!

Comment: @MarkLi what happens when you check for status?

Comment: I have tried to run command - "sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server status" to check status and it said "MySQL is not running"

Comment: @MarkLi So , it is nor running nor you can start it. Have you considered reinstalling it?

Comment: But there are so many different versions. I haven't found any version is exactly for Mac OSX 10.11 EI Captain. Could you provide me a link to right version that works on my Mac? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkLi Have you consider to use Xampp ?

Comment: Thanks Yeikel! I have heard about Xampp but never used it. I can definitely try it out. Yet, will using Xampp solving the my current issue?

Comment: @MarkLi Well , Xampp is a package that includes an easy to install and use Mysql and Apache. They also have a panel to check them and so on. I think it should solve your issue.